# Are environment variables a thing of the past?

Tags: windows, registry, environment-variables

When you can put configurations values in the registry, are environment variables a thing of the past?

Comment: The corollary of this - "should new (windows) programs avoid using environment variables in favour of registry entries?" might be interesting+topical on programmers.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **.NET** and the default way to store per user settings they are stored in **.setting** file in

`%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application` directory.

So this way even registries are things of past.

**[Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)** also gives a way of registering COM components without using registry.

That being said environment variables give a easy way of a passing information from a parent process to a spawned process. This is true for OS X , Windows and Linux. For this they are immensely valuable

Comment: I awarded this answer because it mentioned .setting files

Answer (score 2):

These are completely different thing.
The registry is just for windows, it is global (you can't have variables different per process like you can do for environment variables). And environment variables are more commonly implemented for different languages. You can also easily access environment variables using the %NAME%, and they can copied when you spawn a process from a parent process.

The registry is more like a windows specific database for different applications usage. more often than not, it is not the right solution (but in some occasions it is very useful)

Answer (score 0):

Using environment variables to store configuration settings for an application certainly is (or should be) a thing of the past.  Because of the global namespace, and the lack of any standard naming scheme, there's nothing stopping two different programs from using the same environment variable with incompatible meanings.  (This doesn't happen as often as you might think, but it does happen.)

On Windows, environment variables (as configuration settings) are usually only used by applications that have been ported from Unix.

On the other hand, the system defines various environment variables which Windows applications may use either explicitly or implicitly.  There are some advantages to this approach, particularly the ability to change the environment variables locally in a particular command shell or script and have the modifications inherited by any applications you run from that context.

And, as idanzalz already noted, environment variables also provide an efficient way for a parent process to provide information to a subprocess.